# SQL GROUP_CONCAT alias in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my sql statement:

```
SELECT 
    tA.a1, GROUP_CONCAT(tB.b2) AS b2
FROM
    tableA tA
        LEFT JOIN
    tableB tB ON tA.a2 = tB.b1
WHERE
    CONCAT(tA.a1, b2) LIKE '%somestring%'
GROUP BY tA.a1;
```

I get an sql error saying something along the lines of "unknown column name b2 in WHERE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clause - but in your case that's even senseless, because `WHERE` applies filter to rows that **will be grouped** while `GROUP_CONCAT()` collects rows that are **already grouped**

You may do that, for example, with subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 
    tA.a1 AS ta1, GROUP_CONCAT(tB.b2) AS b2
  FROM
    tableA tA
        LEFT JOIN
    tableB tB ON tA.a2 = tB.b1
  GROUP BY tA.a1) AS grouped
WHERE 
  CONCAT(ta1, grouped.b2) LIKE '%somestring%'
```

Comment: Best answer so far as it explains precisely why WHERE doesn't work here. Also, this solution that uses subquery provides the most amount of insight into the query process.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    tA.a1, GROUP_CONCAT(tB.b2) AS b2
FROM
    tableA tA
        LEFT JOIN
    tableB tB ON tA.a2 = tB.b1
GROUP BY tA.a1
HAVING
    CONCAT(tA.a1, b2) LIKE '%somestring%';
```

Comment: my mistake, didn'T realise OP renamed his group concat to his original column name

Comment: +1 for a solution that works without changing variable and alias names in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

for filtering aggregate functions, use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`

```
select a,  group_concat(b) as b_aggregate from
tbl
where concat(a,b) like "%somestring%" -- not aggregate
group by a
having concat(a, group_concat(b)) like "%somestring%" -- aggregate
```

Comment: +1 for a clear and simple explanation of the distinction between HAVING and WHERE in terms of aggregate functions.